# Not able to access subset of the data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame `df` with 20 columns. I have a user-defined function whose input is the variable name. I am trying to extract the particular column from the data frame and return it. However I get an error after running the following code:

```
p <- function(param){
    df <- read.csv("data.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    var_name <- eval(substitute(param))
    print(df$var_name)
}
```

The function returns `NULL`. I suspect the problem is in `df$var_name` but I don't know how to resolve it. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: use `[[]]` rather than `$` to subset with column names. amd why a need of `eval(subs...())`? you are passing the column names as string right? then directly use it inside `[[]]`

Answer (score 0):

Try `print(var_name)`
Assuming you don't have a column var_name to your data frame. It probably doesn't exist. Assuming your function is right!

Answer (score 0):

> I have user defined function whose input is variable name and I am
>   trying to extract the particular column from the data frame and return
>   it.

The sentence above makes no sense.  Variable name is not the same as column name.

If you have a dataframe `df` with columns `a`, `b`, `c`, then `df` is a variable name while `a`, `b`, `c` are column names (for the dataframe `df`).  So no, your function does not input a variable name.  It inputs a column name.

If you had input a variable name `param`, then the construct `eval(substitute(param))` made sense. It would provide you with the value of this name, e.g.

```
 a <- 5
 b <- "a"
 eval(substitute(b))
```

prints `5`.

Since your param is a column name, the construct `eval(substitute(param))` makes no sense.  You should access the column as

```
df[[,param]]
```

(If `df` would be a matrix rather than a dataframe, you should access its column as `df[,param]` instead).

Comment: I disagree in much of your criticism at the start of your answer : the terms,  column names and variables names are often used interchangeably in my field (biostatistics),  and the dataset, df, would never be called a variable.

Comment: Well, you may use them interchangeably, but they your code will not work.